# how should I import all the images under a folder in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am new to gatsby.js and working on some gatsby starter. Right I have this folder structure `src/content/jobs/job1` where it has `index.md` and a featured picture with it. The way I import this picture is through this query

```
jobs: allMarkdownRemark(
filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/jobs/" } }
sort: { fields: [frontmatter\_\_\_date], order: DESC }
) {
edges {
node {
frontmatter {
title
company
location
range
url
name
pic {
childImageSharp {
fluid(maxWidth: 1000, quality: 90) {
...GatsbyImageSharpFluid\_withWebp
}
}
}
}
html
}
}
}
```

so that I can get all of the posts of every job folder under the /jobs/ path. And inside `src/content/jobs/job1/index.md`, it has this entry `pic: './pic.jpg'`. This is very limiting, since if I wanted to include more pictures for this post, I need to create a `pic2: './pic2.jpg'` entry inside the `index.md` and modify the query at the same time to be

````
```
jobs: allMarkdownRemark(
filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/jobs/" } }
sort: { fields: [frontmatter\_\_\_date], order: DESC }
) {
edges {
node {
frontmatter {
title
company
location
range
url
name
pic {
childImageSharp {
fluid(maxWidth: 1000, quality: 90) {
...GatsbyImageSharpFluid\_withWebp
}
}
pic2 {  <----- new query for the newly added picture
childImageSharp {
fluid(maxWidth: 1000, quality: 90) {
...GatsbyImageSharpFluid\_withWebp
}
}
}
}
html
}
}
}
```
````

I been searching online looking for the solutions, and I came across this post: https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/gatsby-image-loop-through-and-display-them-dynamically-on-component-page~0d56c1bf-183b-494c-b61b-6957a2406192

However it doesn't address my problem since it targets a pre-defined folder as in

```
{
   resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
   options: {
     name: `logos`,
     path: `${__dirname}/images/logos`,
   },
}
```

but in my case I have`src/content/jobs/job1`,`src/content/jobs/job2`,`src/content/jobs/job3` or even maybe `src/content/jobs/job4\` which I can add it later. this solution only works for one specific folder.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a class that gets you all images from a folder of images:

```
import React from "react";
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby";
import GatsbyImage from "gatsby-image";

/**
 * Uses GatsbyImage and GraphQL to return all images.
 * @see https://www.orangejellyfish.com/blog/a-comprehensive-guide-to-images-in-gatsby/
 */
const ImageSupplier = () => {

  // Don't forget to set the size of your image in
  // fluid(maxWidth: 300, quality: 100) {
  const { allFile } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allFile(filter: {
        extension: {regex: "/(jpg)|(jpeg)|(png)/"}, 
        sourceInstanceName: {eq: "imageFolder"}}) 
      {
        edges {
          node {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid(maxWidth: 300, quality: 100) {
              originalName
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }`);

  return ( allFile.edges );
};

export default ImageSupplier;
```

You must define a source instance in your gatsby-config.js:

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src/components/image-folder`,
    name: "imageFolder",
  },
},
```

`allFile.edges` contains all the images in the folder. Use a map function to get all the images. This way you do not have to import manually.

You can test whether your query works in GraphiQL in the browser: `http://localhost:8000/___graphql`

```
query {
  allFile(filter: {
    extension: {regex: "/(jpg)|(jpeg)|(png)/"}, 
    sourceInstanceName: {eq: "imageFolder"}}) 
  {
    edges {
      node {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 280, quality: 100) {
          originalName
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should show you all the images. If there are none you configured something incorrectly.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. However this didn't seem to be working. I suppose I need a folder called `image-folder` under `src/components/` to hold the image files for this to be working. So I did that but the `ImageSupplier` returns an empty array.

Comment: Did you put image files in there? Use GraphiQL in the browser to make sure the query works.

Comment: yes I have a few images under `src/components/image-folder`. also, I assume this function only reads all the image from one pre-defined folder, what if I need to read from different folders?

Comment: @Joji I added how you test for the images in the browser at the end of my answer.
If you want to get images from multiple folders you have to specify each one in your `gatsby-config.js`. In your query you have to specify the `sourceInstanceName` of each of your folders. Don't forget to accept and upvote the answer when it worked. =)

Comment: Hi your solution works and I have upvoted it. But sadly it is not suitable for my situation. I have edited my question to explain why.

Comment: It didn't work for me. `edges` returns an empty array.

Comment: It seems that we cannot use `sourceInstanceName` with `/components/image-folder/` but it works with `/components/`. It's strange???!